# Setting pipeline description in declarative Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

## Background

We develop our Jenkins pipeline using declarative Jenkinsfile scripts.  For example, if we want to set a log rotate policy on a pipeline, we can use the `options` directive.

```
options {
    buildDiscarder( logRotator( numToKeepStr: "30" ) )
}
```

After we run the pipeline, we would see the following log rotate policy on the configuration screen in Jenkins

[image: GUI log rotate policy]

We never make modifications to the GUI ( such as manually configuring log rotate ), instead that should be driven by the Jenkinsfile

## Question

We want to set the description on a pipeline using the Jenkinsfile.  However, we do not see any closures named `description`.  After some research we did find some ways to set description for the builds ( see below ), but not the description of the pipeline itself.

```
        steps {
            script {
                this.setDescription("123")
                currentBuild.displayName = "The name."
                currentBuild.description = "The best description."
            }
        }
```

How do we set the description of the pipeline using a directive in a Jenkinsfile?

Comment: Have added a bounty.  I would be open to expanding this to include programmatic jenkins files and not limiting to only declarative files.

Comment: Chris Maggiulli do you have any thoughts on who I should award the bounty to?  @VonC's answer works.  I'm glad you validated the second answer from Alexander Pletnev works as well... do you know if that approach also required the Jenkins admin to authorise it?  I was thinking of giving to Alexander Pletnev as VonC clearly has "enough" rep :D  If Alexander Pletnev's solution also did not require authorisation then I'd definitely award to that answer but I suspect it would still need authorisation to work?

Comment: I would personally award to @VonC because his answer was in direct reference to the question

Comment: @AJP As far as I remember any custom Groovy code that uses Jenkins "internal" classes/methods outside of `script {}` declarative block requires admin approval, even JobDSL definitions. That's why they should be parametrized - if you approve one signature, you can then use it again without approvals. The advantage with regards to job descriptions here is that they could be set without rerunning all the thousands of jobs and installing additional plugins. The downside is actually the same - the description for a particular job couldn't be updated by running that job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a pipeline description in a Jenkinsfile, you can try, in theory, the `properties` step, assuming you have the [Project Description Setter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/project-description-setter/) Jenkins plugin installed.
The `properties` step allows you to define job properties, which include the description of the pipeline itself through the plugin, using the [`org.jenkinsCi.plugins.projectDescriptionSetter.DescriptionSetterWrapper`](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/plugin/project-description-setter/org/jenkinsCi/plugins/projectDescriptionSetter/DescriptionSetterWrapper.html).

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: "30"))
    }
    properties([
        [class: 'org.jenkinsCi.plugins.projectDescriptionSetter.DescriptionSetterWrapper', description: 'That is the pipeline description.']
    ])
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        // Post actions if any
    }
}
```

But [`jenkinsci/project-description-setter-plugin` PR #1](https://github.com/jenkinsci/project-description-setter-plugin/pull/1) casts doubt on that approach:

> I doubt you really want to use this plugin as is from Pipeline. Better to just do something like Groovy Post-Build does and permit a statement to set the description to some string. If you want to readFile that is your business.

The `Groovy Post-Build` plugin allows users to execute a Groovy script in the Post-Build step of a job, which can then modify the build or the project, including setting the build or project description.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: "30"))
    }
    stages {
        // Your build stages
    }
    post {
        always {
            script {
                // Assuming "this" is a reference to the job
                def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME)
                // Set the description of the job (pipeline)
                job.description = 'This is the pipeline description.'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Second solution using `Groovy Post-Build` errors with "Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod jenkins.model.Jenkins getInstance. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature."

Comment: @AJP Yes, you might need to ask a Jenkins admin to authorize it.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes had to run three times and approve three times for `method hudson.model.AbstractItem setDescription java.lang.String`,
`method jenkins.model.Jenkins getItemByFullName java.lang.String`,
`staticMethod jenkins.model.Jenkins getInstance`
Thanks.

Comment: @AJP OK. Did the job description changed?

Comment: I was able to get the second example working as well.  I have accepted your answer

Answer (score 4):

Jenkinsfile [declarative syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline) does not assume defining the description.

But if you aim to define all the configuration in code, it makes sense also to create the jobs themselves using code. The [Job DSL](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl/) plugin (AFAIR, it's included in Jenkins by default) handles it:

```java
// pipelineTemplate.groovy

multibranchPipelineJob("Project/Subproject/Job_Name") {
  displayName "Job name displayed in Jenkins UI"
  description """
    This is the job description.
    <br>
    It could be multiline, contain ${variable} substitutions,
    and supports a safe subset of HTML
    so <a href="https://example.com">links</a> also work.
  """.stripMargin().stripIndent().trim()
  factory {
    workflowBranchProjectFactory {
      scriptPath("path/to/Jenkinsfile")
    }
  }
  branchSources {
    branchSource {
      source {
        bitbucket { // other sources are supported
          // the parameters that usually are defined only via UI go here
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // other stuff can also be defined here
}
```

To make it work, one would have to set up a [seed job](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl/#plugin-content-getting-started) that runs [`jobDsl`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/job-dsl/) step(s):

```java
// Jenkinsfile
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage("Generate the jobs") {
      jobDsl targets: "pipelineTemplate.groovy"
    }
  }
}
```

This approach allows to create the whole project/folder structure with as many jobs as required. To scale it, one can define the parameters in YAML files, running `jobDsl` in a loop iterating over the list of them and passing the YAML- objects via the `additionalParameters` argument.

More details could be found on https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/ or better `YOUR_JENKINS_URL/job-dsl-plugin/` as it would contain the APIs of other plugins installed to your instance.

Comment: This is a great design but my system has thousands of jobs that are managed in a different systemic way not using Jobs DSL.  It would be impractical for me to implement this now,

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli I understand. But how you manage them now? Do they use a limited number of Jenkinsfiles that is feasible to edit?

Answer (score -1):

You may add the below code to your `groovy script`, Please make sure you have installed the `Project Description Setter` plugin to your `Jenkins`

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: "30"))
    }
    properties([
        [class: 'org.jenkinsCi.plugins.projectDescriptionSetter.DescriptionSetterWrapper', description: 'I am the pipeline description']
    ])
```

Comment: This is the same solution as @VonC already proposed.

Comment: Undoubtedly, There could be same solution for a problem!